# Can I set the index value of a list to a changing variable in this example?

Tags: python, list

I am a total beginner to Python and recently had a question while experimenting with lists. I have a for loop that increases a variable 'x' and generates a random number every time. I want to add this random number to a list, but when I try assigning the index value of the random number to x, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
import random as number

x = 0
values = []
while x < 9:
  values[x] = number.randint(1,91)
  x += 1

print(values)
```

Comment: There's nothing in `x` yet, so you're indexing an empty list. Don't use `values[x]`, use `values.append(number.randint(1, 91))` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import random as number

values = [number.randint(1,91) for _ in range(9)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Lists do not have infinite memory, you must tell Python how many elements there are if you are going to add values at arbitrary indexes. However, you can also add or delete elements, so it is very common to start with an empty list and use `.append()` to add elements. Here is what you want to do instead:

```
import random as number

x = 0
values = []
while x < 9:
  values.append(number.randint(1,91))
  x += 1

print(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you initialize the list with `values = []` the list size is zero and there are no indexes. And when you do `values[0] = num` the zeroth index doesn't exist, hence the error. But if you initialize your list with `values = [None] * num` it will create a list with `None` in it (`num` times).

```
import random as number

x = 0
values = [None] * 9
while x < 9:
  values[x] = number.randint(1,91)
  x += 1

print(values)

# [82, 91, 16, 80, 77, 9, 61, 78, 72]
```